# KVO binding a CGFloat on SCNNode

Tags: swift, binding, scenekit, key-value-observing, cgfloat

I'm trying to bind the position of a node - in this case, my pointOfView node - to a text field on macOS (but I guess it would be the same on iOS)

I can bind (via `.bind` or Storyboard) e.g. `scnView.pointOfView.camera.fieldOfView`. But I can't bind `scnView.pointOfView.position.x`

I can, however, bind `scnView.pointOfView.position`. But that doesn't seem useful for the text field.

**Details**

Here's what I get with

```
field.bind(.value, to: self, withKeyPath: "scnView.pointOfView.position.x", options: nil)
```

> 2019-01-11 11:54:13.987696+0100 Scenekit Test Template[45791:1781975] Failed to set (contentViewController) user defined inspected property on (NSWindow): [ valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key x.

And here's binding just the `.position`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can always use value transformer to get specific component of a compound value. Something like this:

```
field.bind(.value, to: self, withKeyPath: "scnView.pointOfView.position",
    options: [.valueTransformer: PositionXValueTransformer()])
```

Where ValueTransformer might look like this:

```
class PositionXValueTransformer: ValueTransformer {
    override class func transformedValueClass() -> AnyClass {
        return NSString.self
    }

    override class func allowsReverseTransformation() -> Bool {
        return false
    }

    override func transformedValue(_ value: Any?) -> Any? {
        guard let position = value as? SCNVector3 else {
            return ""
        }

        return "\(position.x)"
    }
}
```